# Additional information: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32. vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class PersonalInfo
    Private Sub Guna2GradientButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BUTTNEX.Click
        PD1.Hide()
        PD2.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Guna2GradientButton3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Guna2GradientButton3.Click
        PD2.Hide()
        PD1.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub NEXYAT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NEXYAT.Click
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-39ATE1Q;Initial Catalog=INFINITYMATRIMONY;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO perdetails VALUES(@CBGENDER,@DOB,@CBHEIGHT,@TXTCOUNT,@TXTSTATE,@TXTCITY,@TXTEDU,@TXTWORK,@CBINC,@CBMS,@CBMT,@CBRELI,@TXTFNAME,@TXTEMAIL,@TXTPH,TXTPASS)", conn)
        command.Parameters.Add("@CBGENDER", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CBGENDER.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DOB.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@CBHEIGHT", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CBHEIGHT.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@TXTCOUNT", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TXTCOUNT.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@TXTSTATE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TXTSTATE.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@TXTCITY", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TXTCITY.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@TXTEDU", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TXTEDU.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@TXTWORK", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TXTWORK.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@CBINC", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CBINC.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@CBMS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CBMS.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@CBMT", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CBMT.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@CBRELI", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CBRELI.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@TXTFNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TXTFNAME.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@TXTEMAIL", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TXTEMAIL.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@TXTPH", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TXTPH.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@TXTPASS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TXTPASS.Text

        conn.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Possibly command.Parameters.Add("@TXTPH", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TXTPH.Text, Try Cint(TXTPH.Text)?  Would also advise tuning "Option Strict On" that will point out any type miss-match while coding

Comment: In addition to Hursey's comment, I suggest that you specify the columns in the insert statement. Also, you should use `conn.Dispose()` after `conn.Close()`, or better use `Using` for the connection as shown in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection).

Comment: @Hursey, it's worth noting that, while I absolutely agree that `Option Strict On` is the way it should pretty much always be, it would not help in this case because the `Value` property of a `SqlParameter` is type `Object`. The fact that there's no error on the `"@DOB"` parameter is evidence of that. It's up to the developer to have the sense to assign an value of the appropriate type. Any data of a different type should be validated and converted first.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, there's no need or point to calling both `Close` and `Dispose` as they do the same thing.

Comment: @user17922293 true that, but of course implement the connections with a using block and there is no need to call either

Comment: @user17922293 Dispose will close but Close does not Dispose. They do not do the same thing.

Comment: @Hursey I agree that Option Strict should be on but it will not help here. The datatype of Value property is not checked against the DbType in the code window.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First validate you user input with TryParse.

DBAs have been known to change database schema without informing developers. Listing the fields along with the parameters in your Insert could save you hours of tracking down a type mismatch.

A comma at the end of the `Using conn` line allows us to have the command (which also needs to be disposed) in the same `Using` block.

Note that the `Value` properties for `@DOB` and `@TXTPH` are using the second parameter in the `TryParse`s. This is filled in with the converted value when the parse is successful.

```
Private Sub NEXYAT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NEXYAT.Click
    Dim DOB As Date
    Dim PH As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TXTPH.Text, PH) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number for PH.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not Date.TryParse(DOB.Text, DOB) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid date for DOB")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim strSQL = "INSERT INTO perdetails (CBGENDER,DOB,CBHEIGHT,TXTCOUNT,TXTSTATE,TXTCITY,TXTEDU,TXTWORK,CBINC,CBMS,CBMT,CBRELI,TXTFNAME,TXTEMAIL,TXTPH,TXTPASS) 
                                                        VALUES(@CBGENDER,@DOB,@CBHEIGHT,@TXTCOUNT,@TXTSTATE,@TXTCITY,@TXTEDU,@TXTWORK,@CBINC,@CBMS,@CBMT,@CBRELI,@TXTFNAME,@TXTEMAIL,@TXTPH,TXTPASS)"
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-39ATE1Q;Initial Catalog=INFINITYMATRIMONY;Integrated Security=True"),
        insComm As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
        insComm.Parameters.Add("@CBGENDER", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CBGENDER.Text
        insComm.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DOB
        insComm.Parameters.Add("@CBHEIGHT", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CBHEIGHT.Text
        insComm.Parameters.Add("@TXTCOUNT", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TXTCOUNT.Text
        insComm.Parameters.Add("@TXTSTATE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TXTSTATE.Text
        insComm.Parameters.Add("@TXTCITY", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TXTCITY.Text
        insComm.Parameters.Add("@TXTEDU", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TXTEDU.Text
        insComm.Parameters.Add("@TXTWORK", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TXTWORK.Text
        insComm.Parameters.Add("@CBINC", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CBINC.Text
        insComm.Parameters.Add("@CBMS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CBMS.Text
        insComm.Parameters.Add("@CBMT", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CBMT.Text
        insComm.Parameters.Add("@CBRELI", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CBRELI.Text
        insComm.Parameters.Add("@TXTFNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TXTFNAME.Text
        insComm.Parameters.Add("@TXTEMAIL", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TXTEMAIL.Text
        insComm.Parameters.Add("@TXTPH", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PH
        insComm.Parameters.Add("@TXTPASS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TXTPASS.Text

        conn.Open()
        insComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```